# Can't see Dataflow Data Pipeline Details

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I've imported a dataflow job as a Data Pipeline in the Dataflow Job's UI
been able to set schedule to this pipeline but i can't see the pipeline details
Is there something wrong or maybe i lack permission in the project?

Thanks.
[image]

**Edit:**
Yes I'm able to see the Pipeline on the Main Page, and the individual Pipeline also works and i can see it.
And i can confirm it is indeed triggered by the Data Pipeline schedule.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What permissions do you have on the project? I don't believe it is a permissions issue as you are able to access/view other details in the UI.

Can you view this pipeline on the main page? Also, on the individual Pipeline Details page, what all information can you view?

Comment: I've edit my Questions with the answer to your questions.
I have editor role in the project.
Yes i am able to see the pipeline in the main page, and i can see all information in the individual pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you create a support case ? I will then take a closer look. Ideally you should be able to see the pipeline details.

Comment: Yes will do, Manav. Thank you. I will create it ASAP